# Does not always click checkbox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a process that involves downloading monthly reports.

```
    //Set Call handler
    Select handlerdd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchType")));
    handlerdd.selectByValue("select");

    //Wait
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Search, choose is exactly as the filtering option
    Select searchcriteriadd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.content-form:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > "
            + "                                                             tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > select:nth-child(2)")));
    searchcriteriadd.selectByVisibleText("Is Exactly");

    //Search box
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchString"));
    search.sendKeys("File I Want");
    search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Explicitly wait until element is seen
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("td.content-grid-th-delete > input:nth-child(1)")));
    //Checkbox
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.content-grid-th-delete > input:nth-child(1)")).click();

   //Wait 
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Generate Report button click
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("fieldset.content-buttonbar:nth-child(10) > legend:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

The process goes as follows

1. From a dropdown menu (handlerdd), the select option is chosen and a search bar appears.
2. The search filter is set to "IsExactly" and the text "file I am looking for" is sent to the text field followed by enter.
3. There is one option, and the checkbox for that option is selected.
4. Then the generate report button is clicked.

I am not completely sure what the problem is. One likely thing that could be happening (besides my checkbox not working) is that the generate report button is being clicked before the file is checkmarked. I am not entirely sure how to avoid this problem. Should I increase the implicit wait time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case WebDriver finds Generate Report button before loading the filtered data.

You give try using `Thread.sleep();`. Following code may help you.

```
//Set Call handler
Select handlerdd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchType")));
handlerdd.selectByValue("select");

//Wait
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Search, choose is exactly as the filtering option
Select searchcriteriadd = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.content-form:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > "
        + "                                                             tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > select:nth-child(2)")));
searchcriteriadd.selectByVisibleText("Is Exactly");

//Search box
WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#searchString"));
search.sendKeys("File I Want");
search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Explicitly wait until element is seen
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("td.content-grid-th-delete > input:nth-child(1)")));

//Checkbox
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.content-grid-th-delete > input:nth-child(1)")).click();

    Thread.sleep(7000);//You can specify time according to your load time

    //Generate Report button click
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("fieldset.content-buttonbar:nth-child(10) > legend:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

Let me know if it worked.